# bss section end address is less than start address

Tags: c, linker, embedded, linker-scripts

I am looking at ARC processor map file and found a section which end address is less than start address.

Is this normal or a bug in the linker script or other issues?

```
Section name         type     start addr    end addr    length
RM0_SECTION          bss       00040000    0003ffff     00000000
```

Comment: 'length 00000000', I guess.  If it was 00040000/00040000, that would mean length  00000001, ie. 'first valid address is 00040000, last valid address is 00040000'.

Comment: Wonder if it might be more an oddity of the software outputting the sections. would be surprised if this is how it is represented in the actual generated file.

Answer (score 1):

This is a normal behavior.
The formula to comply with is the following:

```
length = "end addr" - "start addr" + 1
```

So:
- if the section is not empty, `end addr` corresponds to the last address that belongs to the section.
- if the section is empty, `end addr` equals `start addr - 1`, which means that `end addr` is NOT an end address in this case, as you observed for *RM0_SECTION*.